# Git Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

I made a change in dev branch and commited the change.

To then swisted to master and tried a merge.

```
Switched to branch 'master'
root@li494-175:/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig# git merge --no-ff development
Auto-merging rtb_settings/rtb_settings.yaml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in rtb_settings/rtb_settings.yaml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I dont know what this means.  I Tired to swtick bakc to master and I get this error.

```
root@li494-175:/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig# git checkout development
rtb_settings/rtb_settings.yaml: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I just dont get this at all. How do I resolve?

Comment: Open the referenced file in a merge tool or a text editor. You should find merge markers `<<<<<HEAD`, `==========`, `>>>development` or similar where merging failed - you will need to edit those fragments to the desired result, add and commit them. Did you consult any documentation before asking?

Comment: That post sovled my problem.  Thanks